# How to access the Terminal's $PATH variable from within my mac app, it seems to uses a different $PATH

Tags: swift, macos, swift2, swift3

I'm trying to make a mac app where the user can type in commands just like they would in the mac terminal, I got most of it working however I found out that the $PATH variable of apps run from the finder or xcode is different than the $PATH variable the Terminal uses.

I can run commands and also found a way to add a predefined path to the application's $PATH variable but I need a way to automatically read the Terminal's $PATH variable and copy it to the Application's $PATH variable. This should be automated as users will have different path's inside their variable.

I also found out that when I run the application from the terminal with "open appname.app" the correct $PATH variable is used (the same one the terminal uses)

This is my code so far:

```
    let task = Process()
    var env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
    var path = env["PATH"]! as String
    path = "/usr/local/bin:" + path
    env["PATH"] = path
    task.environment = env
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = ["echo","$PATH"]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    print(output)
```

This will add "/usr/local/bin" to the Application's $PATH but I need a way to copy the values from the Terminal's $PATH.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a remark: Terminal.app itself has no $PATH. When you open a Terminal window, a *shell* process is started (/bin/bash is the default on macOS, but it can be configured in the user's settings). The shell then reads some init files (.profile, ..., depending on the shell).

Comment: I'm sure you know this, @MartinR, but for the sake of the OP: It doesn't just "read" those files, it *executes* the commands within them. Therefore, the resulting shell PATH can be the result of arbitrary computation. There's not really a way to obtain it without performing that same computation. (It's even possible, though not typical, for the shell PATH to be different every time.) And executing those startup files does more than *just* compute PATH and can have side effects. So, executing them just to determine PATH seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Adding bash Shell Path

The default shell paths can be found in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/path.d/`. One way to read the shell paths is to use the `path_helper` command. Extending the code example above and using bash as the shell:

```
let taskShell = Process()
var envShell = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
taskShell.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
taskShell.arguments = ["/bin/bash","-c","eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s) ; echo $PATH"]
let pipeShell = Pipe()
taskShell.standardOutput = pipeShell
taskShell.standardError = pipeShell
taskShell.launch()
taskShell.waitUntilExit()
let dataShell = pipeShell.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
var outputShell: String = NSString(data: dataShell, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
outputShell = outputShell.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
print(outputShell)

let task = Process()
var env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
var path = env["PATH"]! as String
path = outputShell + ":" + path
env["PATH"] = path
task.environment = env
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $PATH"]
let pipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = pipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
var output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
output = output.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
print(output)
```

Note:

1. This code example calls the shell in non-interactive mode. This means that it won't execute any user specific profiles; such as `/Users/*userid*/.bash_profile`.
2. The paths can be listed multiple times in the `PATH` environment variable. They will be traversed from left to right.

### References

There are a couple of threads on application and shell PATH's for OS X which provide more context
[How to set system wide environment variables on OS X Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107787/how-to-set-system-wide-environment-variables-on-os-x-mavericks)
and 
[Setting the system wide path environment variable in mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks)

Comment: This does not seem to pick up the user PATH settings when running in debug mode under Xcode or have I missed something?