# How to launch a terminal app on PATH in Swift on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos

I want to launch a terminal application (like "git") in my Swift application on macOS. My code looks like this:

```swift
    do {
      let process: Process = Process();
      process.launchPath = "git";
      process.arguments = [
        "..."
      ];
      process.launch();
    } catch {
      print("Cannot launch git: \(error)")
    }
```

On my box git is on PATH and launches without problems in a terminal by just running `git`. How can I accomplish that in my Swift application too?

Can `Process` be made to resolve the application path on its own or do I have to do that myself? And if I have to do it manually, how would I do it?

**Update:**
The start application is a GUI application, which can run from Finder as well as being debugged from Xcode.

I can read the PATH like this:

```
var env = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
var path = env["PATH"]! as String
```

but that value doesn't contain the terminal's PATH values.

Comment: Is it a command line app or a GUI app? For the latter, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41535451/1187415

Comment: You are suggesting to read the PATH values, construct a file path for each and try to access each of them to see if the file exists?

Comment: GUI apps have a different environment than your Terminal session, that makes it a bit more difficult. For a command line app it should be sufficient to launch "/usr/bin/env" with "git" as an argument, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/26973384.

Comment: Indeed that works for `git` (which is in `/usr/bin`), but for a custom path which is on PATH that doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify first: Is this a GUI app (started from the Finder) or a command-line app which you run from the Terminal?

Comment: Or do you run it from within Xcode? In that case the problem is that Xcode (as a GUI app) has a different environment.

Comment: I updated my question with that detail.

Comment: Try launching `"/bin/bash"` with the arguments `[ "--login", "-c", "git ..."];` , compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/58828362/1187415

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the linked solutions work for me. I get errors like `path_helper operation is not permitted`. However, even with some errors I can get `git` to launch somehow, but not other terminal apps, which are not in `/usr/bin`. Maybe because my GUI app doesn't have the same env variables. So I will first try to get this solved.

Comment: Sandboxing is another possible problem.

Comment: I got it to work. You were close by suggesting to launch an own shell (`/bin/bash`) for the process. If you like you can post an answer here to get the points. I'll change it to include the actual solution I used.

Comment: You are welcome to post your solution as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment from @MartinR brought me to the right idea. Don't run the terminal command directly, but from a new shell. This way it will do the PATH resolution for you:

```swift
    let shellProcess = new Process();
    shellProcess.launchPath = "/bin/bash";
    shellProcess.arguments = [
      "-l",
      "-c",
      // Important: this must all be one parameter to make it work.
      "mysqlsh --py -e 'print(\"Call from shell\")",
    ];
    shellProcess.launch();
```

This example uses the MySQL shell as example, which is in `/usr/local/bin` (unlike git, which is in `/usr/bin`). Git worked already in the beginning, while mysqlsh did not. From the comment you can also see that it is important to make the mysqlsh call a complete and single parameter entry. If you split that then `/bin/bash -c` will only execute `mysqlsh` and not pass on the given shell parameters.